# Align content vertical and horizontal to content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align image to div (.md4 - boostrap) horizontal and vertical...

I try do this like:

```
             <div class="front" style="height: 820px; width: 820px; vertical-align: middle;" >

                    <div class="inner" style="float:none; margin:0 auto;">

                        <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg"/>

                    </div>

             </div>
```

But it doesn't work. Its still align only in one way.

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tzvze7ew/

What i do wrong ? And how should its look for work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `transform` to center both vertically and horizontally.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div:first-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="submain">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="inner">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution won't support all the browsers. Because transform is CSS3 property.

We can achieve through javascript. What we can do is lets calculate the height of the browser and divide by 2 and minus 50% height of the image.

Below is code

```
.img {
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Javascript
Lets say your image height is 150px.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var height = window.innerHeight;
   var new_height = (height/2) - 75; // Half of 150 of 75.
   $('.img').css('margin-top', new_height+'px');
  });
</script>
```